# What is the difference between "a por" and "por"?

Tags: preposiciones

Reading the blog for the Vuelta a España, I find the entry

> Michael Storer (Team DSM) se marcha solo a por la victoria a 3 de meta. 17" sobre Verona y Sivakov y 4 minutos al pelotón.

I know what it means. He took off alone for victory, but why is it *a por la victoria* and not just *por la victoria*? I have looked up the entries for both *a* and *por* in the DLE, but without finding any example there. I do not think it can be a typo since the heading for that entry was

> Storer se marcha a por el triunfo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAE has an [article about this](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/ir-por-agua-o-ir-por-agua). It seems that the usage of "a por" is exclusive to Spain, and I can say that it is common there.

In Spain, "a por" **after a verb of movement** means "to look for", or "to fetch/get", such as

> *Voy a por agua* (I am going to get water).

RAE indicates that there is no reason to consider this usage incorrect, and that it is useful in some cases to avoid ambiguity due to the many meanings of *por*. The example RAE gives is

> *Voy a por mi hijo*

which unambiguously means "I am going to pick up my son", whereas

> *Voy por mi hijo*

may mean "I am going to pick up my son", but it may also mean "I am going because of my son", or "I am going for my son's sake", or "I am going because my son asked".